# How can i read .DTD file using C#

Tags: c#, dtd

I have a  .DTD file, I need to read using C#.
I will be very grateful if any one gives me some link/sample

Thanks
Sagar

Comment: You mean interpret/parse I assume, not read? It's a simple text file so *reading* it should be done using any class or method in the framework that can read text files.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with [DtdProcessing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.dtdprocessing(v=vs.110).aspx). When the XML points to a DTD you have here a way to set or get if processing (validating the XML) is done or not. From there you should find your way home :)